# How to remove curly brackets in a two dimensional array near the edges?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

Suppose I have a matrix {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}. I want to remove the curly brackets near the edges, i.e., I want an output as '{1,2,3},{4,5,6}'. Somebody please help me to solve it.

Comment: for display purposes you can use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html): e.g., `Row[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ","]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 4):

For display purposes you can use [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html): e.g.,

```
 Row[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ","]
```

[image]

**Update:** to get `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` from `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` use [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html):

```
Join @@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Comment: @atanu, please see the update.

Comment: thanks again. Actually my intention was to use for 'Join' purpose.