# Remove outermost curly brackets for table of variable dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I have $\vec k=(k_1,k_2,...,k_d)$, where $d$ is variable. I want to construct a table that iterates $a_i$ from $0$ to $k_i$, over a function of $\vec k$ and $\vec a$. Here is what I did (here $k$ will vary):

```
k = {1, 2, 3};
d = Length[k];
A = Array[Subscript[a, #] &, {d}];
ran = Transpose[{A, ConstantArray[0, d], k}]
```

which outputs $\{\{a_1,0,1\},\{a_2,0,2\},\{a_3,0,3\}\}$.
I wish to make a table like

```
Table[f[k,A], ran]
```

but this fails because the outermost curly brackets in 'ran' don't belong. How do I remove them? I tried using the function Row (see trick used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205017/how-to-remove-curly-brackets-in-a-two-dimensional-array-near-the-edges)), but I couldn't convert it back into the table.

Comment: `Table[f[k,A], ##]& @@ ran`?

Comment: whoa, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
Table[f[k,A], ##]& @@ ran
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the accepted answer:

```
Table[f[k, A], Sequence @@ ran // Evaluate]
```

`Sequence @@ ran` replaces a list by a [sequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html), so effectively removes the outermost curly brackets. [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) is needed because `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so we need to force evaluation.